# how to initialize complex object from json string in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to initialize a complex object from a Json string as simply as possible

The problem is that when I add a sub-object to an object I don't find the state of my object before it was converted to json.

I find it complicated to do it in Python, in Java Jackson does it automatically. In python I have to make an algo to locate each sub-object and initialize them one by one...

An example here:

```
import json
from typing import List

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Address:
    def __init__(self, street_name, street_num):
        self.street_name = street_name
        self.street_num = street_num

class Home:
    def __init__(self, id: str, personList: List[Person], address: Address):
        self.id = id
        self.personList = personList
        self.address = address


address = Address("name street", 1)

person1 = Person("Bob", 20)
person2 = Person("Jhon", 35)

list_person = list()
list_person.append(person1)
list_person.append(person2)

home = Home("0", list_person, address)

jsonStr =  json.dumps(home, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                      sort_keys=True, indent=4)

loadJson = json.loads(jsonStr)
my_home = Home(**loadJson)

# ok because a dict
print(repr(my_home.address["street_name"]))
# not ok
print(repr(my_home.address.street_name))
```

Do you have a solution ?

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Since you dumped the `__dict__` attribute of your class, you need to either access data as a dictionary or to create a function that will parse your dict-like data into objects